# performance monitoring

Tags: performance, monitoring, io, cpu

Is there some performace monitoring tool which would run in background gathering info about all system activity? Somethimes my system (Arch linux, 32 bit) slows down terribly and the `top` utility doesn't show anything.

I imagine some daemon which would gather info and log it, so when the slowdown pass away I would be able to find what was the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [sar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sar_in_UNIX)?

Comment: The tutorial I used: http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/tutorial.html

Answer (score 3):

The slowdown might not have been caused by CPUs being utilized. Check `iotop` for IO utilization.

Comment: I suppose so. The problem is that often the `top` starts after the slowdown passes away (it is that bad), I suppose the `iotop` will have the same problem. But thanks anyway, I will certainly try it.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of them. If you want it to be basic and command-line, take a loot to `sar`.
Or you could use some monitoring tool with nice web ui. Personally I prefer zabbix, there are also monitorix (very simple to setup), nagios, zenoss and many others.

[Monitorix](http://www.monitorix.org/) is probably what you want on this point.

Answer (score 2):

Consider installing munin.  It will monitor a wide variety of data and provide graphical output.  This is better for monitoring trends.

You may also want to consider run sar in the background.  It can identify a number of issues including CPU, I/O, swap, and other issues.  If you are experiencing problems, this may be your best for your current situation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of open source solutions like those mentioned above (munin, zabbix, nagios, OpenTSDB). There are also commercial solutions like [Metrink](https://www.metrink.com), [DataDog](http://datadog.com), and New Relic. You'll really want to find something that can monitor more than just CPU and disk, as the problem can be in any number of places.